# VBA to Include Check Boxes into Userform that gets checked/unchecked depending on table value

Tags: vba, excel

**The request: Include a check box in my userform that gets checked/unchecked depending on True/False value in column of table**

**Current state**:

I have a user form that is used to add edit or delete entries in a table.
Specifically the editing works in a way that I have a combo box that corresponds with the mail addresses in column A and text boxes for each column of the table.

When you select a mail address in the combo box the text boxes of the user form get filled in with the data from that row.

[image]

For the example I would like to add a **check box** that says **"married"** and corresponds to a column in the table that has "True" or "False" values. This check box should now be checked/unchecked automatically depending on the value in the corresponding column.

**My code:**

```
Private Sub c_01_Change()

' c_01 is the combo box
   With c_01
   ' B_02 is the delete button
   ' B_03 is the save button
        B_02.Visible = .ListIndex > -1
        B_03.Visible = True
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

        ' T_0X are the text boxes
        For j = 0 To UBound(.List, 2)
            Me("T_" & Format(j, "00")).Text = .Column(j)
            Me("T_" & Format(j, "00")).Locked = False
            If j > 2 Then Me("T_" & Format(j, "00")).Text = Format(.Column(j), "0.00")
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub T_00_Change()
    M_text 0
    B_02.Visible = T_00.Text <> ""
End Sub
Private Sub T_01_Change()
    M_text 1
End Sub
Private Sub T_02_Change()
    M_text 2
End Sub
Private Sub T_03_Change()
    M_text 3
End Sub
Private Sub T_04_Change()
    M_text 4
End Sub
Sub M_text(y)
    If c_01.ListIndex > -1 Then c_01.Column(y) = Me("T_" & Format(y, "00")).Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a checkbox.
2. Then check the cell for the value. In my example it is `Cells(1,1)`:
3. Write this:

`CheckBox1.Value = CBool(Cells(1, 1))`